# How to make Wordpress REST API custom endpoint public?

Tags: php, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'd like to make a custom endpoint via plugin but it's not working for the anonymous user. How do you make it publicly accessible? If that's not possible then how do you login via command line?

I've followed [this example](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/routes-and-endpoints/#creating-endpoints). Added the code below to the "hello.php" plugin.

```
function prefix_get_endpoint_phrase() {
    return rest_ensure_response('Hello World, this is the WordPress REST API');
}
function prefix_register_example_routes() {
    register_rest_route('hello-world/v1', '/phrase', [
        'methods'  => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
        'callback' => 'prefix_get_endpoint_phrase',
        'permission_callback' => '__return_true',
    ]);
}
add_action('rest_api_init','prefix_register_example_routes');
```

I enter `https://example.com/wordpress/wp-json/hello-world/v1/phrase` and it works fine for a logged-in user. Anonymous user gets 401 REST API disabled. However, `https://example.com/wordpress/wp-json` works just fine for the anonymous. I'm testing it on a clean Wordpress 6.2.2 installation (permalinks have been set to post name).

Also tried accessing it via command line. I've followed [these instructions](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#basic-authentication-with-application-passwords) (created application password, used curl template):

```
curl --user "username:xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx" https://example.com/wordpress/wp-json/hello-world/v1/phrase
```

The result is 403 Forbidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out it was a hosting issue.

EDIT: I went to DirectAdmin. Clicked on Ochrona stron www (WAF). Selected option Niski and then pressed button Ustaw.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

in order to make your route public for anonymous user you have to remove
`permission_callback`, try the following code

```
function prefix_get_endpoint_phrase() {
    return rest_ensure_response('Hello World, this is the WordPress REST API');
}
function prefix_register_example_routes() {
    register_rest_route('hello-world/v1', '/phrase', [
        'methods'  => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
        'callback' => 'prefix_get_endpoint_phrase',
        //'permission_callback' => '__return_true',//remove it
    ]);
}
add_action('rest_api_init','prefix_register_example_routes');
```

Comment: It turned out my hosting had a security filter that disabled WP REST API. Now it works (with and without the permission_callback). Thank you for your effort anyway.